# Vertical swiping in QtQuick 2.12

Tags: qt, qml

Im currently forced to work with QTQuick and Qt.Quick.Controls 2.12.
I want to find a solution to implement a vertical swiping of pages.
Is it possible to go with SwipeView? Unfortunately the property "vertical" was implemented in a later version.

```
SwipeView {
    id: view
    currentIndex: 0
    anchors.fill: parent


    Item {
        id: mainPage
        PageMain{}
    }

    Item {
        id: secondPage
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the `orientation` property help?

Comment: Works. Thanks a lot :) Its hard to google for the correct properties when working with an older version.

Answer (score 0):

```
SwipeView {
    id: view
    currentIndex: 0
    anchors.fill: parent
    orientation: Qt.Vertical

    Item {
        id: mainPage
        PageMain{}
    }

    Item {
        id: secondPage
    }
}
```

I added the 'orientation' property, but you must import QtQuick.Controls 2.15.

Comment: orientation: "Vertical" works perfectly with QtQuick Controls 2.12 (which i cant update). Thanks alot